# Making all possible combination of lists in lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have found several answers to this problem, however it is not what i intended to do.

When I have a list:

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

And I would like to have all possible combinations:

```
[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[4,5,6]
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]
....
```

But is there an easy solution for this in python?

Thanks, and is it also possible to create 1 list instead of 3 like:
    [7,8,9,4,5,6,1,2,3]

Comment: Is the list intentionally repeated twice?

Comment: Sorry my bad, no I'll change it

Comment: @xienixs: Best not to move the goal posts, you've already had answers to your question as it first stood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itertools.permutations` is what you're looking for I think.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(l, len(l)))
[([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]), 
  ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]),
  ([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]), 
  ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]),
  ([7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]),
  ([7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])]
```

And merged together:

```
>>> [list(itertools.chain(*x)) for x in itertools.permutations(l, len(l))]

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6], 
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], 
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3], 
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Perfect! Sorry but now I am using it is it also possible to instead of [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] create [1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9]? Just one list instead of 3?

Comment: you mean merge each combination of the 3 to a single line? or permutations on the whole line? you can do either. if you want to merge the 3 memeber permutation, use `[list(itertools.chain(*x)) for x in itertools.permutations(l, len(l))]`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for permu in permutations(a,3):
...   print permu
...
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6])
([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])
([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3])
([7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
([7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])
```

Combined lists using `reduce`:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for permu in permutations(a,3):
...   print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,permu,[])
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Dagnabbit, impeded by the "are you human" captcha and missed first answer by 8 seconds.

Comment: heh, I got it as well, just got an easier CAPTCHA I guess ;)

Comment: Mine had something that was halfway between an `S` and a `$` in it... burned seconds deciding which!

Answer (score 1):

In Python2.7 you don't need to specify the length of the permutations

```
>>> T=[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations(T))
[([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]), ([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]), ([7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), ([7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])]
```